# Comparing String (.substr()) to Character (.back()) in C++

Tags: c++, string, comparison, character

I am trying to compare whether the last letter of the word "A", and the next letter of the word "B" is the same.

I'm iterating over "B"; and comparing within an if statement:

```
string A = ""
string B = "XYZTTTTLMN"

for (long i = 0; i < B.length(); i++) {

    if ( A.back() != B.substr(i,1) ) { ... }

}
```

I receive an error that says I can't compare a string to a character. But, as far as I can see, A.back() returns a character and B.substr() returns a single digit string, which should be OK?

Any ideas on what I can do?

Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `B.substr(i,1).back()`?

Comment: No, there is no option to directly compare a character to a string. That's forbidden compile-time. Why don't you just access `i`-th element of the string instead of creating a full string?

Comment: [std::string::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) would probably be better. E.g. `A.back() != B.at(i)`

Comment: Also, `A` is an empty string so accessing `back` is UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, a string having size=1 is not same as a character.
This is the reason you are getting error as string and character cannot be compared as you did.

To solve this you can use below code:

```
  for (long i = 0; i < B.length(); i++) {

    if ( A.back() != B.at(i) ) { ... }

  }
```

OR

```
  for (long i = 0; i < B.length(); i++) {

    if ( A.back() != B[i] ) { ... }

  }
```

Comment: There is no need to use `at()` when the index cant ever go out of bounds.

Comment: @RemyLebeau correct, any of the two syntax can be used here

Comment: I wasn't commenting on the syntax, but the functionality. `at()` performs bounds checking at runtime, whereas `operator[]` does not. When the loop is already handling the bounds checking, using `at()` is just wasted overhead with no gain.